# Running an .exe file with a single process .ini file Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe, node-modules, ini

There was a rather interesting question for me, I need to open the .exe file in Node.JS along with its .ini configuration file. There is an already created shortcut that, when you click the mouse, opens the application as it should, you must do the same through Node.JS

Example: object line in a shortcut (which I mentioned above): `D:\Downloads\gobot\bot.exe D:\Downloads\bots\accs\data\Alex_Shivol@192.168.1.1.ini`

Here are some examples I tried:

```js
BotsProcess[0] = exec('D:\\Downloads\\bots\\start.exe D:\\Downloads\\bots\\accs\\data\\Wiley_Beard@46.174.50.52;7800.ini', {shell : true});

spawn('D:\\Downloads\\bots\\start.exe', ['D:\Downloads\bots\accs\data\Alex_Shivol@192.168.1.1.ini'], {shell : true});

spawn('D:\\Downloads\\runBots\\' + files[j], {shell : true});
```

In the last example, I tried to open a shortcut in which all this is spelled out, but the problem is that when opening 2+ shortcuts, as many programs open as you need, but with the same .ini

Comment: So you want to call bot.exe with the path to your ini file as parameter, correct? What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include your code. What errors do you get? What is the expected outcome, and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: Changed the post, added the code